# Cluster LineStrings using HDBSCAN?

Tags: python, clustering, shapely, linestring, spatial-cluster

I am trying to cluster a set of LineStrings (made out of lat/lon Points) with the help of HDBSCAN (using the "haversine" metric). The objective is to define the most "usual" path.

I have only managed to create clusters (polygons) from the original Points so far and I still have to reconstruct the path from the identified clusters which is not easy.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is an efficient way to cluster the LineStrings.

[image]